# How can I display modules according to articles?

Tags: joomla, module, assign, article

I apologize if this question has been asked before but I couldn't find an answer.

I created a main menu with several links to category featured articles and
I would like to assign one module to single article, not assign the modules to the menu positions but for example mod1->art1, mod2->art2... Unfortunately, I do not know how to do it. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Joomla extension called "Advanced Module Manager".

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager#download

This gives you a lot more options and flexibility for assigning modules to different things (including single articles).

The free version has worked just fine for all my sites.

Good luck.